# Is it possible to call own Method in Vue data()?

Tags: vue.js

So I'm using Element Vue, I need to get access to a method or to the value of the 
acceptedDates

```
export default {
data() {
    return {
        acceptedDates: [],

        pickerOptions1: {
            disabledDate(time) {
                return moment(time).isBetween(this.acceptedDates[0], this.acceptedDates[1]);

            }
        }
    };
},
methods: {
    //setting acceptedDates method...
}
```

I get a ReferenceError for this.accptedDates or even without using this. How do you do this?

**Update**
Thank you for the first anwsers, but I still can't figure it out.
I created this fiddle for you to see: https://jsfiddle.net/05nru5xq/13/

If you go to http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/date-picker you will find that disabledDate is a Function in PickerOption.

Comment: `data` is only to specify variables and it's default values, you have `methods` and `computed` to actually process the data, plus you have `mounted()` or `beforeMounted()` to initialize anything you might need

Comment: might now do what you really want, but can be a starting point for how to interact with all methods http://tpcg.io/rswWYN - just click "preview" and then change the first date to `2018-01-20` for example

Comment: @balexandre I can't use mounted in that case, because the parent component is changing all the time but the component it self is not created again. So thus I would only be called once.

Comment: @balexandre I liked your example, but I have a fixed method name disabledDate because of Vue Element. Maybe you could look up my https://jsfiddle.net/05nru5xq/13/ to see what I mean. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I know exactly what you are after, I've updated accordingly to your example https://jsfiddle.net/05nru5xq/31/

some points on your code:

- **never use** capital to name methods, capital letter first is to name Object that can be created with the `new` attribute;
- `today` is not a moment object so you can't call `isBetween` on it
- [from the docs](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/datetime-picker#picker-options) you need to name your options as there's 3 of them, hence specifying the option `:picker-options="{ disabledDate: betweenOneWeek }"`
- `data` is just a place to hold variables, don't put methods there.

As a side note:

I've done the same (bought it for me) and I'm not in any way affiliated with them, just a happy customer. If you want to know VueJs well enough and quick, [try this Udemy course](https://www.udemy.com/vuejs-2-the-complete-guide/learn/v4/content), it's pretty good and worth all the money

Comment: Thank you! Worked really great! To your points: I was like in a hurry (my gf moved in haha) and could not really check all my mistakes. But I never use capital name for methods and I see the the mistake as well with today. But thank you again! And thank you for the Udemy course link! I'll show into it

Answer (score 1):

In the `data` section you can define variables with functions but you're not able to do things like you did. Why? It's simple. You're using `this` which binding to `pickerOptions1` object, not data. Even when you use `arrow function` in object it won't work as well because in that case it will return `window` object.
Those operations on data you can move to separate function and in my opinion it would be the best way.

For example you can do something like that:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    customMessage: 'Test ',
    testFunction() {
        this.customMessage += this.message;
        alert(this.customMessage);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.testFunction();
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mxuh7c9p/

or more suitable to your case:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    acceptedDates: [],
    pickerOptions1: null,
  },
  methods: {
    getDisabledDate(time) {
        return moment(time).isBetween(this.acceptedDates[0], this.acceptedDates[1]);
    },
    setAcceptedDates() {
      const disabledDate = this.getDisabledDate(time);
        // do something
    }
  },
  mounted() {
  //this.getDisabledDate();
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mxuh7c9p/13/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Maybe I'm too tired to see you the solution, but I want to show you my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/05nru5xq/13/ . I need to use a function in pickerOptions1, so I'm not able to see how I can use my methods in there.